# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two short test files in the same folder as follows:

```
pi:~$ cat module.js
export let message = "Hello world";

pi:~$ cat index.js
import { message } from "./module"
console.log(message);

pi:~$ node -v
v14.12.0

pi:~$ pwd
/home/pi
```

I have `"type": "module"` in package.json. I then tried running `node ./index.js`, and got:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/pi/module' imported from /home/pi/index.js
Did you mean to import ../module.js?
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:276:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:673:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:784:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

What did I do wrong? Is the syntax: `import { message } from "./module"` incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the file extension in the `import` statement

```
import { message } from "./module.js"
```

From [`Nodejs Docs - Differences between ES modules and CommonJS:`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs)

> #### Mandatory file extensions
>
> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword.
> Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully
> specified